# angular - translate ng-model which is inside template of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have one directive which is creating dynamic control.Directive's template is as below

```
"<div class=\"form-group\">\n <input type='text' ng-model=\"value|translate\" class='form-control'/>\n </div>"
```

where in my directive scope i have :

```
scope.value = 'VALUE';
```

and in config section i have :

```
.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        'VALUE' : 'Some value'
    });

    $translateProvider.translations('ar', {
        'VALUE': 'بعض القيمة',
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}])
```

but it gives nonassign error : `Error: [ngModel:nonassign]`

how ever by applying filter on `scope.value` in directive and removing translate filter from ng-model solves problem.

```
$filter('translate')(scope.value);
```

and changing `ng-model='value|translate'` to `ng-model=value`

But when user changes language it will not translate this pre-filled value of textbox because its assigned it by translating it as value and filter is not applied on it.

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugnu_pathak/X2fsw/47/)

Comment: Can You make plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: If I understand correctly, [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lobh96u/) for the task you are trying to solve; It is not the best way, but I hope it's help You =)

Answer (score 2):

As say MoLow: you cannot assign a filtered expression to ng-Model;
Angular translate have some [events](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/18_events); You can use it, for change model value; Just:

```
$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function(){
    scope.value = $filter('translate')('VALUE');
};
```

Dnt forget add `$rootScope` to Your directive;

[Example;](http://jsfiddle.net/7y3y9nq7/)

Answer (score 1):

the Error means you cannot assign a filtered expression to ng-Model:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/nonassign

what you should do, is filter the expression in the directive link function, using a watch to change it when the user selects another language:

```
scope.$watch(function() { return $filter('translate')('VALUE'); }, function(newVal){
    scope.value = newVal;
});
```